# Entering Emirates Stadium, Block vs Turnstile

Tags: tips-and-tricks, factoids, tfl, football

I have never been to Emirates Stadium and have tickets for the match tomorrow (10 Dec) with a friend.  The instructions say that unless we enter at the right place we can be refused entry altogether, and that means forfeiting some decent coin.

So the instructions say...

Turnstile: M Stand: Clock End Block: 121 (followed by row, seat)

But when I examine a map of the stadium, like at http://www.arsenal.com/news/emirates-stadium-news/emirates-stadium-seating-plan
 there isn't anything indicating turnstiles.

**Question**: So approaching the stadium, which comes first? Does one look for "Turnstile M" or an entrance marked "Block 121"?

**Secondarily**, I can see the Arsenal Tube Stop and the Holloway Road Tube Stop, one to the Northeast and the other to the Southwest of the stadium, which of these is more convenient to the 'Clock End'?

---

Note (for Zach Lipton):

> You MUST enter through the correct Block (entrance) only! If you try
>   to enter through another Block, you will be denied entrance and will
>   not be able to enter the stadium and see the match.

also this...

> It is important that you will NOT approach any stewards or any
>   personnel working at the club or stadium.

Comment: Surely if you turn up at the wrong entrance they would send you to the correct place, not confiscate your tickets?

Comment: Calling this a "travel" question is really stretching my imagination. What prevented you from calling the stadium's office and simply asking them?

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't address my comment at all. This has nothing to do with travel. It is a question for those who run the stadium. If those who run the stadium say "we don't answer questions" then that's silly but it doesn't change anything! Perhaps you can find a message board or forum dedicated to Arsenal fans?

Comment: Getting an answer does not make your question on-topic.

Comment: This is a darn odd set of rules. Did these tickets come from a legitimate source?

Comment: @ZachLipton it's in chat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Arsenal (Piccadilly Line) is the nearest tube station, around three minutes walk from the ground](http://www.arsenal.com/emirates-stadium/get-to...-emirates-stadium#4DY1D5AkFl86jCsx.99). Holloway Road is not a good choice because *Holloway Road station will be exit-only before and after matches with pre match eastbound trains non-stopping. Drayton Park is also closed on match days.* (ibid.)

On the way in or out you might want to make a slight detour along Drayton Road, to cross the Clock End Bridge. Clock End is the southern part of the stadium (near Queensland Road). The bridge is shown on the right here (courtesy Dreamstime.com):

[image: Clock End Bridge]

Once at the stadium, the turnstiles are your starting point. "E" is shown in the centre and "D" on he right:

[image: Turnstiles E and D]

Block 121 is in the Upper Tier, slightly to the East of the goal posts (as in your map).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Plus although Holloway Road Tube is closer, Arsenal Tube allows access making this answer doubly correct.

Answer (score 4):

When I go to google maps, street view, I can just about see/read one of the information boards outside the Stadium and see letters on it with arrows, for entrances I am sure, and just inside the building there is a banner with Clock End.

My virtual location was on Benwell road.

I'd say the nearest underground station would be Holloway Road, if that information is right.

But the best information you find on the [site of the stadium](http://www.arsenal.com/emirates-stadium/get-to...-emirates-stadium)
That site [has a map](http://www.arsenal.com/assets/_files/images/feb_13/gun__1359992120_stadium_layout_guide.jpg)

I see what you mean by 'no turnstile information', I am sure there will be information on those boards I saw in street view, or on temporary ones.
Otherwise, ask one of the many volunteers who are always around or one of the others waiting to get in.